# Refactor data for duplicates in an associative array

Tags: php, associative-array

I've got the following array of data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [tag] => tag-a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [tag] => tag-b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [tag] => tag-a
        )
)
```

Where there are duplicate IDs I want to refactor `tag` so it's formatted like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => tag-a
                    [1] => tag-b
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => tag-a
                )
        )
)
```

I've been able to get something working by looping through a 'duplicate report'. But wonder if there's a more efficient way to achieve this array structure?

Comment: We can only judge if there is a 'more efficient way' if you share your current one (I'd hazard a guess that adding a meaningful key to the resulting array would optimize things a little though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Convert source array to hash table (`key => value` array).
2. Build desired result array from hash table.

Implementation:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $el) {
    if (!isset($result[$id = $el['id']])) $result[$id] = array();
    $result[$id][] = $el['tag'];
}

$result = array_map(
    function ($id, $tags) { return array('id' => $id, 'tags' => $tags); },
    array_keys($result), array_values($result)
);
```